# Permutations in an Urn Problem, with Finite Number of Balls

Tags: combinatorics

In general I think I understand permutations fairly well.   A simple example of permutations is drawing balls from an urn.    I have 3 colors of balls, blue, green, and red, and I have 5 balls of each.

How many color patterns of balls can be drawn from the urn ?   In this case the order of the color matters, but all balls of a single color are the same.

Answer:  Simple,  this is  3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 =  243

**Now Here Is The Real Question**

What happens if I have fewer balls of each color than I will be drawing.  What if I have 3 balls of each color, and want to draw 5 balls ?

Clearly the answer is fewer than 243, because some of the previous options are not available.  But what is the equation?    And more importantly, can it be generalized to a larger problem so if I had 30 balls of each color, and wanted to draw 50 balls total, I wouldn't have to do something like calculate the full set of permutations, and the subtract out the permutations where I have 31 of a color, and 32 of a color, etc

Comment: The "simple" answer is incorrect.  There are by definition $15!$ ways to draw those $15$ balls from the urn.  You seem to have counted the number of *color patterns* that can arise when you draw only $5$ balls from the urn (with or without replacement).  When drawing $5$ balls without replacement, there are $15^{(5)}=15!/10!=15\cdot 14\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 11$ ways to draw them.

Comment: whuber:  color patterns is what I am looking for here.   That is what I intended to express with  "in this case the order of the color matters, but all balls of a single color are the same"

i'll try to edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: OK, thank you.  Incidentally, the answer with 50 balls drawn without replacement from an urn of 30 balls of each color is 717830847380662283155566.  It is about 99.9906% of $3^{50}$.

Comment: Aha!  clearly you know the equation for this, because that number is too large to simulate.    Can you explain ?

Comment: It's just brute force, I'm afraid.  I computed the polynomial $$(x_1+x_2+x_3)^{50}$$ modulo the ideal generated by $\{x_1^{31}, x_2^{31}, x_3^{31}\}$ and then set all three variables to equal $1$.